# Form URL in Sharepoint Workflow Email

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, email

I have a workflow setup to run when I submit an infopath form. I am trying to create a HyperLink in the email to the infopath form using

```
[%Current Item:URL Path%]
```

However it generates this url

```
https://sharepoint.someschool.edu/VPAA/coursefee/Rollover+Requests/1-3-3-2013-08-21T14_06_29.xml
```

instead of what is the valid URL.

```
https://sharepoint.someschool.edu/VPAA/coursefee/rollover%20requests/1-3-3-2013-08-21t14_06_29.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Eric,

I normally use:

> [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]

It has usually worked for me since it gives the full path to the file including the site URL and not just a server relative URL like the Current Item one does.

Comment: [%Current Item:Encodeded Absolute URL%] is what I ended up going with. Not sure what the pros and cons are though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a hyperlink that points to a specific item, and the path to where these items are will not change, you could hard code the beginning of the desired URL and append the current item's ID to the end:

```
https://sharepoint.someschool.edu/VPAA/coursefee/rollover%20requests/[%Current Item:ID%].xml
```

This may help avoid the trouble all together!

Answer (score 2):

As Eric answer above mentions, [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%] will work, no need to over engineer this solution.  I've done this and it works fluid.  Of course I create a text that says "click here" then put that fule in as a hyperlink to that associated text.

Caveat to all this I've noticed however - if your workflow is a SharePoint 2013 workflow, it may not actually work right.  I think they're still working out bugs in O365.  I had to set mine up using the SharePoint 2010 Workflow for it to actually work properly.

Just FYI if you find yourself having issues in the 2013 version your not alone!

Comment: This answer is more suitable as a comment on the answer by T0t3sMcG0t3s. And that you can do once you gain enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

[%Current Item:Encodeded Absolute URL%] is what I ended up going with. Not sure what the pros and cons are though.

Comment: I've just tried with 
[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]
and it gives a URL with an item number at the end of the link.
Bottom line is that the link leads to a 'page not found'.